# How to evenly distribute content across an html cell for a newsletter?

Tags: html, html-table, html-email

This is a newsletter so its heavy on tables and can't use much CSS but I'm sure there must be a solution.

I have a design I'm working on with the title of the newsletter at the top. Directly under that I want it to read Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec. Directly under that will be the start of the first content section.

This is a snippet of what I've got so far but its not justifying how I want. I'm trying to find a solution to have those months evenly spread across the 450px width. If necessary I can put a table inside that row. I'm sure this is something simple I'm just not seeing.

```
<table>
    <tr><td width=10px></td><td width=450px>Title</td></tr>
    <tr><td width=10px>
    </td><td width=450px>
        <span style="text-align: justify;">
                    Jan Feb Mar Apr May Jun Jul Aug Sep Oct Nov Dec
        </span>
    </td>
    <tr>
        <td style="background-color: #5DB1E3;" width=10px>&nbsp;</td>
        <td style="background-color: #4D4D4D;" width=450px><span style="color: #FFF;">Industry Updates</span></td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td width=10px>&nbsp;</td><td width=450px>
```

Comment: I would put all the months in table with 12 columns

Comment: How would I then distribute the cells evenly in that table aside from manually dividing the 450px width by 12 and putting that as the width of each cell?

Comment: if you set the table width to 450px, the cells will divide automatically

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/QymYH/ here you go

Comment: hmm I would've sworn I had tried that earlier but must've missed something. thanks. If you make it an answer with the code I'll happily mark it the answer for you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you place it in a table with a set width, the cells inside will justify on their own.

```
<table width=450px>
  <tr>
    <td>Jan</td>
    <td>Feb</td>
    <td>Mar</td>
    <td>Apr</td>
    <td>May</td>
    <td>Jun</td>
    <td>Jul</td>
    <td>Aug</td>
    <td>Sep</td>
    <td>Oct</td>
    <td>Nov</td>
    <td>Dec</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Here it is in http://jsfiddle.net/QymYH/

Thanks,

Pedro

Comment: thanks all I can guess is that I set the td width to 450 but not the nested table when I had tried this method. worked great though now.